# Move records from dashboard to different users in php

Tags: php, mysql

I m making an app that contains complaint from different department all can be show on dashboard now there are three and four user that handles those request daily all the application is handled by main dashboard and other users hav a sub dashboard i wanted to move complaints to different users somehow from main dashboard so they can entertain 10 or 20 request and forward it somewhere else later how can i do it?

Comment: Have you got any specific code you need help with that you can post?

Comment: what do you mean, " how can i do it" ? you have to write code. You should try to ask more detailed. What's exactly your problem? DB structure, logic, or ....??

Comment: no i dnt hve any. issue is i ve multiple user and each of them hve a dashboard and an admin manages a main dashboard he sends some complaints to each of the users dashboards where they handle the complaints they get from the main dashboard i m working on php  and i ve no idea how should i manage this